# Module.exports not working for custom angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, browserify, angularjs-filter

So I have an angular app laid out like the following:

```
'use strict';

//lib dependencies listed out
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQuery = $;
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

//controllers
var rootCtrl = require('./controllers/rootCtrl');
var reportCtrl = require('./controllers/reportCtrl');
var myReportsCtrl = require('./controllers/myReportsCtrl');
var userCtrl = require('./controllers/userCtrl');
var modalCtrl = require('./controllers/modalCtrl');

//factories
var userFactory = require('./factories/userFactory');
var authTokenFactory = require('./factories/authTokenFactory');
var authInterceptor = require('./factories/authInterceptor');

//directives
var exertion = require('./directives/exertion');

//filters
var reportType = require('./filters/reportType');

var ui_router = require('angular-ui-router');
var ui_router_extras = require('ui-router-extras');
var ui_bootstrap = require('ui-bootstrap');

var routes = require('./routes');

var namespace = 'main';

var angular = require('angular');

var run = require('./run');

var app = angular.module(namespace, [
    // inject:modules start
    'ui.router',
    'ct.ui.router.extras',
    'ui.bootstrap'
    // inject:modules end
], function config($httpProvider){
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
})
.constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:5000')
.controller('rootCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$modal', 'UserFactory', rootCtrl])
.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', modalCtrl])
.controller('reportCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', reportCtrl])
.controller('myReportsCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', myReportsCtrl])
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', userCtrl])
.factory('UserFactory', ['$http', 'API_URL', 'AuthTokenFactory', '$q', userFactory])
.factory('AuthTokenFactory', ['$window', authTokenFactory])
.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['AuthTokenFactory', authInterceptor])
.directive('etExertion', [exertion])
.filter('reportType', reportType)
.config(routes)
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'UserFactory', run]);
module.exports = app;
```

And a filter as thus:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function() { return function(input, report_type) {
  input = input || [];
  var out = [];
  angular.forEach(input, function(item){
    if(item.name == 'Other' || item.report_type == report_type)
      {
        out.push(item);
      }
    });

    return out;
  }; }
```

Whenever I try to include the filter like so:

```
.filter('reportType', function(){  return function(input, report_type) {
  input = input || [];
  var out = [];
  angular.forEach(input, function(item){
    if(item.name == 'Other' || item.report_type == report_type)
      {
        out.push(item);
      }
    });

    return out;
  }; })
```

Everything works but if I do it how it was done before I can't get the console to log and angular doesn't perform the filtering correctly. What am I doing wrong here? If I log the reportType variable to the console in my main application I get the same thing as what's in my filter file.